# How do you deploy a basic HTML file to the root directory of an Azure Bot function app?

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-functions, azure-bot-service

I created a Bot App Service in Azure from the LUIS template and configured continuous integration. The Bot Service is a function app, and works locally and within the web-windows in Azure and on [dev.botframework.com](https://dev.botframework.com/).

My goal is to deploy a basic HTML page to the root directory `BOT_NAME.azurewebsites.net` of my app service.

**Current attempts to solve:**

I have configured Web Chat and have an I-Frame as such:

`<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/<BOT_NAME>?s=<SECRET>'></iframe>`

I have attempted to modify the `run.csx` file with the following:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var stream = new FileStream(@"index.html", FileMode.Open);
response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
```

This correctly displays `index.html` at `localhost:3979/api/messages`. When deployed to Azure, I attempted to fully qualify `index.html` as `d:\home\site\wwwroot\index.html`, yet `<BOT_NAME>.azurewebsites.com/api/messages` returns the following:

`The HTTP 'GET' method is not supported by the 'GenericJsonWebHookReceiver' WebHook receiver`

I have created a new function app (*not* bot app) in an effort to launch the base HTML file and utilize Azure's web-proxy feature to map the URL `\wwwroot\index.html` to `\`. This works, but it isolates the app into two repositories, and thus feels out of practice.

I have also attempted to modify `function.json` to include `"authLevel": "anonymous"` to no avail.

Please help! I would really appreciate it, as I'm unaware of the best practice to implement such a solution. Within Azure, *all* out-of-the-box Bot templates are function apps now, hence anyone wishing to launch an HTML bot page will likely need details. Thank you!

The example solution contains the following:

[image: Current solution contents]

Comment: 'This works in general purposes' - what do you mean by this? I would expect the proxies route to be your best bet.

Comment: it works in a general Azure function but not using the Bot framework. The Bot framwork does't expose the proxy section of the function in Azure portal, hence my suggestion of a second function to point to the first. Can I provide you any additional details?

Comment: @MattMason-MSFT I updated the post as per your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the Bot Services UI does not expose the Azure Function Proxies section. However, you can still use it as Bot Service is still a Function App.

Here's what you can do.

**Enable Function Proxies**

To enable function proxies, Add the following to the App Settings of the Function App.

```
ROUTING_EXTENSION_VERSION ~0.2
```

You can access the tab by Bot Service > Settings > Application settings > App settings

**Add Index.html**

Add the index.html with the iframe for the bot at the wwwroot/index.html

**Add a New Function to expose index.html**

Create a new HTTP Trigger function that reads index.html and returns it as a http response.
[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnsSA.png)

Function.json

```
{
 "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

run.csx

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(@"d:\home\site\wwwroot\index.html", FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

**Add proxies.json**

Finally add a proxy to have the root of the function app point to the new function.

```
{
    "proxies":{
        "home":{
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://<<FUNCTION_APP_NAME>>.azurewebsites.net/api/home"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I used App Service Editor to add the function app and proxies files. You can find it at Bot Service > Settings > Advanced Settings > Development Tools > App Service Editor.